# Abbreviating IPv6 addresses

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is an array with IP addresses. I need a selected IP address to shorten. For example:

```
['fcef:b0e7:7d20:0000:0000:0000:3b95:0565']
```

abbreviation rules: if a part beginning 0 need to del from part or there is e.g. `0000` need to change it to `0`.
The previous example after abbreviation:

```
['fcef:b0e7:7d20:0:0:0:3b95:565']
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Show us your code.

Comment: Why you dont remove the zero from `b0e7:7d20` ?

Comment: Kasra: because this is the task. :)

Comment: JGreenwell:  it is a part of a task

Comment: logic? one address is one string row I try more idea but I'm stuck with. Maybe is there a built in  ipv6 manipulation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module from the standard library:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> str(ipaddress.ip_address('fcef:b0e7:7d20:0000:0000:0000:3b95:0565'))
'fcef:b0e7:7d20::3b95:565'
>>> ip = ipaddress.ip_address('fcef:b0e7:7d20:0000:0000:0000:3b95:0565')
>>> ip.compressed
'fcef:b0e7:7d20::3b95:565'
>>> ip.exploded
'fcef:b0e7:7d20:0000:0000:0000:3b95:0565'
```

---

This shortens the ip under the actual rules.

To shorten the ip with only the rule you cite, you can simply use `replace`:

```
>>> 'fcef:b0e7:7d20:0000:0000:0000:3b95:0565'.replace('0000', '0')
'fcef:b0e7:7d20:0:0:0:3b95:0565'
```

Comment: Because the full task (in two step): 
ip: 2001:0db8:03cd:0000:0000:ef45:0006:0123
- Each of the groups leading zeros omitted. For example, the way described above
address 2001: DB8: 3CD: 0: 0: ef45: 6: 123
- Two or more groups only zeros can be simplified two colon
empty between groups. With this rule further simplifying the previous address:
2001: DB8: 3CD :: ef45: 6: 123

Comment: and the last rule: - If there are several places in title only zeros groups, then only once the latter method can be implemented abbreviation. In such a case always the more number of zero group should be shortened. If the group is located in the same number of zeros in many places, it is to be shorten only once the first from left. For example: 2001:0000:0000:00f5:0000:0000:0000:0123
shortened: 2001:0:0:f5::123

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression within `join` as following :

```
>>> ':'.join('0' if i.count('0')==4 else i.lstrip('0') for i in s.split(':'))
'fcef:b0e7:7d20:0:0:0:3b95:565'
```

or as @J.F. Sebastian mentioned in comment you can just use `i == '0000'` instead of `count` !

```
>>> ':'.join('0' if i=='0000' else i.lstrip('0') for i in s.split(':'))
'fcef:b0e7:7d20:0:0:0:3b95:565'
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian :) yeah! so simple! how i miss that?